# How to run C++ program using GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to run a demo program, `ba_demo.cpp`, which is in a folder structure, "C:/root/demo_parent1/demo_parent2/demo.cpp", and this file uses the following code in it.

```
#include "root/sub1/sub2/header_file.h".
```

The file is at

```
'C:/root/sub1/sub2/header_file.h'
```

When I try to compile the demo program by the command

```
C:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2> gcc demo.cpp
```

it is not finding the header file and is throwing an error. What changes should I make to my command in order to run the demo program successfully?

Comment: First off, you aren't executing anything with `gcc demo.cpp`, that would compile it (creating an executable program).  Then you'd need to run it.  That said, do you have a file `header_file.h` in `c:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2\root\sub\sub2\`?

Comment: @nerdwaller yes..i do have a header_file.h..but in C:/root/sub1/sub2

Comment: Where is your header file on the path though

Comment: @LucasHolt how can i set the path?

Comment: You could try using the -I flag to gcc to specify the path to look for header files on. Also, since this is a C++ program you probably want to use g++ rather than gcc.

Answer (score 3):

First you must inform your compiler where to look for `root` directory by adding flag `-IC:` 
so your command will look like this:

```
C:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2> g++ demo.cpp -IC:
```

But that's not practical. Better change include to

```
#include header_file.h
```

and add only /root/sub1/sub2/ directory, which will look like this:

```
C:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2> g++ demo.cpp -IC:\root\sub1\sub2\
```

Now you have your program compiled to `a.out` file. You execute it by

```
C:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2>./a.out
```

You can change output name to `demo.exe` like this:

```
C:\root\demo_parent1\demo_parent2> g++ demo.cpp -IC:\root\sub1\sub2\ -o demo.exe
```

Please note that since you work on Windows under some &nix simulator the slashes in my examples might be wrong but I can't check them now. Use google to check how to handle them properly.

EDIT: Also, don't forget to take Lukas Holt's advice and use g++! It is very important to use proper compiler for proper language.

Comment: If the slashes are a problem, usually syntax like this works /c/root/sub1/sub2/ in cygwin bash shells and things.

Comment: I have never worked under Cygwin, and last time I worked under MinGW I had slahes totally mixed up and everything worked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your .cpp file is in: `C:/root/demo_parent1/demo_parent2/demo.cpp`

You include:

```
#include "root/sub1/sub2/header_file.h"
```

This is a relative path. You need either to specify an include directory with the -I flag, or to move header_file.h to C:/root/demo_parent1/demo_parent2/root/sub1/sub2/header_file.h.
The most simple solution would be to just `#include "header_file.h"` and to move it into the same directory as demo.cpp.

Then you will be able to compile it with gcc, and to execute the generated file.